# Need HTML of displayed page turned into PDF

Tags: php, html, pdf-generation

I have a webpage that is fully built out and displays exactly as needed. I received a requirement from my boss to now take that same page and turn it into a PDF. I have a rather old installation of DomPDF and upgrading is not an option due to PHP being 5.6.40 and newer versions of DomPDF require PHP 7.1 or greater. Additionally, I have an equally old version of fPdf on the host. Also, all the docs for DomPDF seem to elude to me needing to have all my HTML in a variable to be used by DomPDF. Again, not an option as the page is already fully built out and very jQuery intensive.

So, what options do I have for converting an existing HTML page to a PDF?

I desperately need a solution to this. Thanks everyone!

Comment: what about making a dedicated CSS for **media="print"** and export it s pdf using the default one in the browser.

Comment: Wow! I never thought about that as an option! I'll have to try that and drop some feedback here. Great suggestion, Mohammed!

Comment: @MohammedYassineCHABLI - Is there a way to execute this "export" you're referring to programmatically?

Comment: Of course,  **window.print();**

Comment: Ahhh....yeah, that won't work as the application needs to create the PDFs as part of a page post and store them on the server as well as show them to the user.

Comment: I was able to get it to work using PHP's file_get_contents('URL to page') and then carry that over into $dompdf->loadhtml();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it to work using the following strategy;

```
$f = file_get_contents("URL to page I wish to convert");
$dompdf->loadHtml($f);
```

This worked great all except for the rather painful shortcomings that dompdf has with pulling in styling properly.

Answer (score 1):

How about using **jsPDF** extension, it runs on **jQuery** too and converts HTML to PDF without any server side effort. I am not much into PHP and never used DomPDF as well. Also we can have different CSS styles to the page elements for printing to PDF to make sure all contents fit the view.

```
var doc = new jsPDF(); 
var specialElementHandlers = { 
    '#editor': function (element, renderer) { 
        return true; 
    } 
};
$('#submit').click(function () { 
    doc.fromHTML($('#content').html(), 15, 15, { 
        'width': 190, 
            'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers 
    }); 
    doc.save('sample-page.pdf'); 
});
```

Check the working Codepen example 
(https://codepen.io/connectpritam/pen/wvKqwLG)

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, Pritam. I'll investigate this library further also.